# R - Why does frameex[ind, ] needs a ", " to display rows

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have troubles understanding how displaying an index works.

```
# Find indices of NAs in Max.Gust.SpeedMPH
ind <- which(is.na(weather6$Max.Gust.SpeedMPH))

# Look at the full rows for records missing Max.Gust.SpeedMPH
weather6[ind, ]
```

My code here works, no problem but I don't understand why `weather6[ind]` won't display the same thing as `weather6[ind, ]` . I got very lucky and mistyped the first time.

I apologize in advance that the question might have been posted somewhere else, I searched and couldn't find a proper answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See ["Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: It is helpful to understand what each part does. Indexing matrices/vectors is handled using `[rows,cols]`. Run each part in the console and see what you get. `is.na(weather6$Max.Gust.SpeedMPH` will produce a logical of `TRUE/FALSE` entries. Add the `which` and you'll get the indices where your logical is true. You'll then subset `weather6` with a vector. This vector will determine what `rows` are selected, since it is placed in the `rows` place. See a [more in depth explanation here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Answer (score 2):

So `[` is a function just like any other function in R, but we call it strangely. Another way to write it in this case would be:

```
'[.data.frame'(weather6,ind,)
```

or the other way:

```
'[.data.frame'(weather6,ind)
```

The first three arguments to the function are named `x`, `i` and `j`. If you look at the code, early on it branches with the line:

```
if (Narg < 3L)
```

Putting the extra comma tells R that you've called the function with 3 arguments, but that the `j` argument is "missing". Otherwise, without the comma, you have only 2 arguments, and the function code moves on the the next `[` method for lists, in which it will extract the first column instead.